# That’s what I’m talking about / That's what I am saying

Tags: meaning, grammar

In *Inside Out* animation we have Joy that says:

> And... we’re out.
>   That’s what I’m talking about: another perfect day! Nice job everybody! Let’s get those memories down to Long Term.

What does it mean: That’s what I’m talking about...
Can we replace it with: That's what I am saying...

Comment: That's what I am talking about is used here to show, that everything went as planned or better.

Comment: Can we replace it with :That's what I am saying...???

Comment: Not in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal meaning of **Now that's what I'm talking about** is along the lines of: in the middle of a conversation about some topic, with examples being given, someone or something comes into view that typifies the thing being spoken of, and the speaker draws attention to it.

**That's what I'm saying** is fairly close in meaning, but rather than a third party person or object, they are referring to something that the second person ***said***.

I'm a little stuck for an example, but let's say we're talking about tiny dogs wrapped up in coats against the winter:

> A: I saw a tiny dog walk past the other day in this little coat, looked just like a burrito ...
>   B: [looks puzzled]
>   [small dog walks into view, wrapped up in tartan, looking like a burrito]
>   A: ... that's what I'm talking about.

versus

> A: I can't help but laugh when I see those little dogs with tiny legs wrapped up like hotdogs in little tartan coats ...
>   B: They look just like burritos!
>   A: Yeah, that's what I'm saying

Not actually a very good example (sorry!). Maybe watch [***The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fresh_Prince_of_Bel-Air) (Wikipedia) - Will Smith uses at least the first of those phrases many times.